Kafka Unable to push data onto S3 Bucket. -- Serialization Error
I am quite new to this, so please bear with me.
So I am trying to Push Realtime Streaming Data Produced by Kafka on my Aws S3 Bucket. Kafka is able to produce data in the broker. And in the consumer Code you see down below, checkpoint folders are being created in my s3. But my realtime data produced by kafka is not getting pushed into the bucket. Please help!
Consumer Code
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from config import configuration
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,StringType,DoubleType,IntegerType,TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json,col


def main():

    from pyspark.conf import SparkConf


    spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("RealtimeStreaming")\
    .config("spark.jars.packages", 
                "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13:3.5.0,"
                "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1,"
                "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.469" )\
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")\
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", configuration.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY"))\
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", configuration.get("AWS_SECRET_KEY"))\
    .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider')\
    .getOrCreate()

    #print(spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll())

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('WARN')

    vehicleSchema= StructType([
                StructField("id", StringType(), True),
                StructField("deviceId", StringType(), True),
                StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True),
                StructField("location", StringType(), True),
                StructField("speed", DoubleType(), True),
                StructField("direction", StringType(), True),
                StructField("make", StringType(), True),
                StructField("model", StringType(), True),
                StructField("year", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("fuelType", StringType(), True)                             
                ])

    gpsSchema= StructType([
                StructField("id", StringType(), True),
                StructField("deviceId", StringType(), True),
                StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True),
                StructField("speed", DoubleType(), True),
                StructField("direction", StringType(), True),
                StructField("vehicle_type", StringType(), True)
                ])

    trafficSchema= StructType([
                StructField("id", StringType(), True),
                StructField("deviceId", StringType(), True),
                StructField("cameraId", StringType(), True),
                StructField("location", StringType(), True),
                StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True),
                StructField("snapshot", StringType(), True)
                ])

    weatherSchema= StructType([
                StructField("id", StringType(), True),
                StructField("deviceId", StringType(), True),
                StructField("location", StringType(), True),
                StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True),
                StructField("temperature", DoubleType(), True),
                StructField("weatherCondition", StringType(), True),
                StructField("precipitation", DoubleType(), True),
                StructField("windspeed", DoubleType(), True),
                StructField("humidity", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("airQualityIndex", DoubleType(), True)
                ])

    emergencySchema= StructType([
                StructField("id", StringType(), True),
                StructField("deviceId", StringType(), True),
                StructField("incidentId", StringType(), True),
                StructField("type", StringType(), True),
                StructField("location", StringType(), True),
                StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True),
                StructField("status", StringType(), True),
                StructField("description", StringType(), True)
                ])
    

    def read_kafka_topic(topic, schema):
            try:
                return (spark.readStream
                    .format('kafka')
                    .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'broker:29092')
                    .option('subscribe', topic)
                    .option('startingOffsets','earliest')
                    .load()
                    .selectExpr('CAST(value AS STRING)')
                    .select(from_json(col('value'), schema).alias('data'))
                    .select('data.*')
                    .withWatermark('timestamp', '2 minutes')
                    )
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")
                raise

    def streamWriter(DataFrame, checkpointFolder, output):
        return(DataFrame.writeStream
               .format('parquet')
               .option('checkpointlocation', checkpointFolder)
               .option('path', output)
               .outputMode('append')
               .start()
               )

    vehicleDF=read_kafka_topic('vehicle_data', vehicleSchema).alias('vehicle')
    gpsDF=read_kafka_topic('gps_data', gpsSchema).alias('gps')
    trafficDF=read_kafka_topic('traffic_data', trafficSchema).alias('traffic')
    weatherDF=read_kafka_topic('weather_data', weatherSchema).alias('weather')
    emergencyDF=read_kafka_topic('emergency_data', emergencySchema).alias('emergency')

    query1=streamWriter(vehicleDF, checkpointFolder='s3a://realtime-datastream-bucket/checkpoints/vehicle_data',
                 output='s3a://realtime-datastream-bucket/data/vehicle_data')
    query2=streamWriter(gpsDF, checkpointFolder='s3a://realtime-datastream-bucket/checkpoints/gps_data',
                 output='s3a://realtime-datastream-bucket/data/gps_data')
    query3=streamWriter(trafficDF, checkpointFolder='s3a://realtime-datastream-bucket/checkpoints/traffic_data',
                 output='s3a://realtime-datastream-bucket/data/traffic_data')
    query4=streamWriter(weatherDF, checkpointFolder='s3a://realtime-datastream-bucket/checkpoints/weather_data',
                 output='s3a://realtime-datastream-bucket/data/weather_data')
    query5=streamWriter(emergencyDF, checkpointFolder='s3a://realtime-datastream-bucket/checkpoints/emergency_data',
                 output='s3a://realtime-datastream-bucket/data/emergency_data')
    
    query5.awaitTermination()



if __name__=="__main__":
    main()

Here is the Error

org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:441)
... 46 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/bitnami/spark/jobs/spark-realtime.py", line 131, in <module>
main()
File "/opt/bitnami/spark/jobs/spark-realtime.py", line 126, in main
query5.awaitTermination()
File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming/query.py", line 221, in awaitTermination
File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in call
File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 185, in deco
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.StreamingQueryException: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = a1964eae-4521-408a-a0c4-43546366574d, runId = 60a6c320-4a1c-42de-8663-07b8ab5bf91c] terminated with exception: Task not serializable


have you tried writing different job for each stream?
